# sorting by time column in data store using google app engine

Tags: java, sorting, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using google app engine to save comments on my website. I would want to sort these by a particular column. I save the time a comment is posted in this column. So the datastore looks like this

```
id              message         time
name=seth       good luck       Jul 30, 2014 2:04:06 PM
name=henry      good luck       Jul 30, 2014 7:03:31 PM
```

Now i would like to sort the entities by time. 
I am using Java as the language for this.

This is how i am writing the query to give me sorted results by time (comment is the entity name)

```
Query q = new Query("comment").addSort("time", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);
```

This surely does not work. I went  through the docs but could not figure out a way to achieve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you did not make "time" an indexed property. From the documentation:

> A query can't find property values that aren't indexed, nor can it
>   sort on such properties. See the [Datastore Indexes](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/indexes#Java_Unindexed_properties) page for a detailed
>   discussion of unindexed properties.

UPDATE:

You store it as a String. It will sort it as a String, not by time. You should store it as a Long value - it will save you a lot of space and the sorting will be correct.

Comment: No, the property is indexed. Here is how i set it. e1.setProperty("time",DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(cal.getTime())); Also confirmed this, by using this method. e1.isUnindexedProperty("time"), it returns false.

Comment: Then, what do you mean by "it surely does not work"?

Comment: i meant the query i have does not sort it by time.

Comment: is there any way i can make sense of the string and sort this as time ? GQL is very new to me.

Comment: You can sort dates stored in an ISO 8601 format (e.g. `2014-07-28T06:07:34+00:00`), but not in the format that you are using.